In what ways can Emacsclient freeze the server?
Often I find my Emacs server frozen and I end up resolving it by exiting Emacsclient.
Can Emacsclient somehow freeze the Emacs server?
EDIT: ok, I've found one way to freeze the Emacs server. If I launch ivy-switch-buffer in Emacsclient, then my Emacs server window freezes until something has been selected in ivy-switch-buffer or it's aborted.

emacsclient is just an emacs launcher

Right, and can it somehow freeze the other Emacs that it's connecting to?

This happens so often now. My GUI Emacs is not responding to anything, no matter what I throw at it. If I kill the emacsclient that I have in GNU Screen, then it unlocks and I can use it.

So after you do emacsclient -f '(ivy-switch-buffer)', you cannot click on a different window in your Emacs (or do C-x o)? I cannot reproduce that. Please provide more details.
